# Why are some applications able to reach the network and others are not?

Tags: networking, firefox, brave

On a Dell XP 9310 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed, I am seeing an intermittent issue where the network seems to drop for only certain applications.  The only way to restore it (that I have figured out thus far) is to restart the computer.

I primarily use Brave as the browser, and Evolution as my email client.  This works well *most* of the time.  I noticed that suddenly webpages wont respond and Email will show as being disconnected. This also seems to affect NextCloud and MS Teams.   If I try to `ping`, `wget`, `curl`, etc. something using Terminal, it's working.  If I use Firefox, it's also working.

If I restart the computer, it will be working for a while.

There is no AV or firewall currently installed (didn't get that far).

This affects both wired and wireless connections the same way.

I am really at a loss for what could be different about Firefox and some of the other applications.  The only think I can think of is that the applications affected are all installed after the OS was setup, whereas Firefox and the terminal utilities are native and came installed with Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. If you're connected via Wireless, check your MTU with `ip link`
or `ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'` it should be 1492, not 1500